# Distribute Points on Faces By an Exact Amount? (Geometry Nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a simple geometry node setup, where I'm distributing a cube on a plane. I don't want any of the cubes to be overlapping, so I turned up the distance min on the distribute points on faces node. Is there any way to tell the Geometry Nodes to distribute an exact amount of cubes on the plane? For instance, can I distribute exactly 1,000 cubes on the plane?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this node setup:

[image]

it deletes all indexes which are greater than a number.

The attribute statistic node gives information about the geometry which is plugged in the attribute. Here the index is plugged in. Index is running from 0 - 1299. So if i now delete all indices which are greater than 299 i got exactly 300 points. I didn't instance anything and i didn't join geometry because i just wanted to show which nodes are necessary so - in my opinion - it is easier to understand.

Here an example with the instancing:

[image]

and here the node setup with the "input geometry":

[image]

Note: Index is counting from 0. So if you say greater than 1000, you will get 1001 cubes. So enter greater than 999 and you will get 1000 cubes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you give a little more info on this? For one thing, I want to see the plane, so I added a join geometry node, to join the plane back in. Then I still couldn't see the cubes, so I added the instance on points node, after the distribute points on faces node, and plugged the object info node into that with the cube as the object. What value do I change to make the exact number of cubes?

Comment: just change the 300 to 999 in the greater than node. i updated my answer

Comment: @RyanKingArt: i hoped you know the instance on points node, because you made a tutorial with it here: https://youtu.be/lrhlOBWXd7Y

Comment: Thanks for the information. I still have a problem though. I want the cubes to not be overlapping, so I turned up the distance min a little. The problem with that, is that it removes the cubes that are overlapping, so the number now isn't exact. Is there a way to still use the distance min, and still have an exact number of cubes?  Also, in the screenshot, you added a density max of 80.800. Is that number important at all? What number should it be set to? Because if I change the density max, it adds more or less cubes.

Comment: Yes, the number is important. The number says how „dense“ the distribution should be. If you now increase your distance, of course you get less points/instances and if this number is then lower than your limit you won‘t get your exact number. So to get your exact number you have to raise that value until the number of your points are higher than the limit you want to have. That’s why I plugged in a viewer to check the value of the points.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome